# parameters in jquery ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to find out what parameters I can pass to a jQuery ajax call.

What I am used to is writing something like:

```
$.ajax({
....
success: function(response) {
// put callback here
}
....
});
```

So here is my question:

Obviously the "response" variable I put in the success function just takes back whatever the server sends back from the ajax call. Is there any possible way to send **multiple** variables back? Something like:

```
...
success: function(response,httpStatus,whateverElse) {
}
...
```

Or, is there some other way to get the http response codes?

Thanks to whoever can answer this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the `response`'s `status code` on the `success'` third parameter or `complete`'s first parameter, something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    console.log(xhr.status);
  },
  complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
    console.log(xhr.status);
  } 
});
```

Comment: Great, this was the perfect answer!

Answer (score 2):

Further to @Kokizzu you can check the jQuery API site to see what parameters are passed to the other functions http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.

Also another way that I find handy to work out what parameters are being passed when there are no docs available is:

```
success: function() {
 console.log(arguments);
}
```

That will log to the console all of the arguments that were passed to that function when it was called.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have the server send back json `json_encode` in php:

**Php:**

```
$array['status'] = 0;
$array['foo'] = 'bar';

json_encode($array);
```

**Ajax:**

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Then obviously you could have your callback handle those variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  success: function(data, status, xhttp) {
    console.log(status + ": " + data);
  },
  error: function(data, status, xhttp) {
    console.log(status + ": " + data);
  }
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.